# Print a new line in between a list in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list of potentially unknown length like so:

```
list = [[1,2], [3,4,5], [6]]
```

I have a for loop that prints these items out, but I also want to be able to add an extra new line in between.

```
1
2

3
4
5

6
```

I don't want an additional new line after the final item or before the first. I have a for loop that prints out spaces in between the items in the line. However, there are instances where 1 or more indices are empty. In that case, I don't want to add an extra new line. I've managed to figure out if the first or last index is empty and how to deal with that, but not a middle index.

For example the above result should also be obtainable with this:

```
list = [[1, 2], [], [3, 4, 5], [6]]
```

I'm not sure what's the best way to determine this.

Comment: You're right. That's what I meant. Fixed the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't want extra space before or after it sounds like `str.join` will probably be closer to what you want then other answers that print it chunk by chunk, first you need some generator for each chunk formatted on its own:

```
def parse_list(mylist):
    for seq in mylist:
        if seq: #is not empty
            yield "\n".join(map(str,seq))

#with print function
print(*parse_list(stuff), sep="\n\n")

#old print statement (but still forward compatible)
print ("\n\n".join(parse_list(stuff)))
```

you could also just use a generator expression if you only need to use this once:

```
each_block = ("\n".join(map(str,seq)) for seq in stuff if seq)
print("\n\n".join(each_block))
```

Or you *could* condense this to a single line but I wouldn't:

```
print("\n\n".join("\n".join(map(str,seq)) for seq in stuff if seq))
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Use `enumerate()` like this:

```
for i, sub in enumerate(mylist):
    if i: print()  # If you are using Python 2, remove the parentheses
    for x in sub:
        print(x)
```

**Edit**: I misunderstood your question a little bit.  Since your second example list had invalid syntax, I assumed that meant just two sublists.  The comment by PaulRooney has cleared that up, so you can do this:

```
should_print = False
for sub in mylist:
    if should_print: print()
    for x in sub:
        print(x)
    should_print = bool(sub)
```

Comment: You're right it should have been `list = [[1,2], [], [3]]`. This way works as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = [[1,2],[], [3],[5,6,7],[8]]
first = True
for item in list:
    if first and item:
        first = False
        for number in item:
            print(number)
    else:
        if item:
            print('')
            for number in item:
                print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
for idx, i in enumerate(l):
    if i:
        for j in i:
            print(j)
        if idx < len(l) - 1:
            print()
```

Comment: if you add parentheses to the prints it would work for both.

Answer (score 0):

When you say an index is "empty" do you mean it contains `None`?

```
list1 = [[1,2], None, [3]]
```

Or it contains an empty list?

```
list1 = [[1,2], [], [3]]
```

Either way, I think this would work:

```
for i,j in enumerate(list1):
    if j:
        for k in j:
            print k
        if i+1 < len(list1):
            print
```

Edit: The above assumes that your input is always a list of lists, as your question seems to imply.

Comparing the current index to the length of the list to determine whether we're at the end will fail if the list has one or more empty elements at the end, e.g.:

```
list3 = [[1,2], [], [3], []]
```

This will output:

```
(start)
1
2

3

(end)
```

Note that there's a line break after the 3, which it sounds like you wouldn't want. You'd need some additional logic to account for that, if it's a possibility.

Comment: Sorry I meant `list1 = [[1,2], [], [3]]`

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [[1, 7, 3], [], [7, 10], None, [2, 3, 4]]
for i, v in enumerate(list):
    if v:
        if i != 0:
            print
        for x in v:
            print x
```

Comment: just so you know `if i != 0:` could be simplified to just `if i:`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Thanks and yes, I'm aware. However, the purpose of what is happening is more clear this way.